# How to uninstall mysql

Tags: server, mysql

I try to uninstall `mysql` but getting error

```
  askaran@jaskaran-OptiPlex-3020:/var/run/mysqld$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
     libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: mysql-common:i386 (>= 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
     mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common but it is not going to be installed
     mysql-client-5.5 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: All of the packages listed with missing dependencies are part of MySQL/MariaDB. What happens if you add them to the list of packages to remove in the `apt-get` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install`, and then `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`.

Comment: Not working with this

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal And what is the output you get when you try? Sadly, "Not working with this doesn't provide any clues as to what is happening. Please [edit] your post to include the actions and results of any potential solutions you have tried. Thank you for helping us help you!